# Is it safe to cook in Corelle/Vitrelle on 250 degrees celsius?

Tags: toxicity, food-safety

I have this habit where every morning I cook two fillets of tilapia for breakfast. I've been doing it every morning for over a year now.

I do the cooking directly on the plate I'm eating on. I'll rub some avocado oil on a plate, put the two fillets on it, season it, and put it in the oven just like that. When it's ready I put the plate on the table (with a wooden shim below the plate so the heat won't damage the table) and I eat directly from the plate. Not having to wash an extra dish every day means a lot to me.

I've been using plates made from porcelain and ceramics. Slowly over this time they've been breaking. So I ordered some plates from Amazon:

These are made from an advanced material called Vitrelle, a complex glass-like material. They're completely white with no markings, and they're marketed as oven-safe. I cooked my tilapia in them a couple of times and they didn't break, so that's good. But then I thought to call Corelle and ask them to what temperature these plates are oven-safe. I spoke to the Corelle representative and he said the plates are oven-safe up to 176 degrees Celsius. (That's 350 Fahrenheit.) But I cook my fillets at 250 degrees Celsius (which is 480 Fahrenheit.) I could cook them at a lower heat but then they'd take longer to cook and I don't have much spare time in the mornings.

Now of course, just because he said they're only safe up to 176 degrees doesn't necessarily mean they're not safe at 250 degrees. Maybe they are but the company doesn't want to take responsibility for that since most people won't check that when buying the product, so maybe it's just a cover-your-ass policy.

My question is: **Do you think it's safe to cook in Corelle plates on 250 degrees Celsius?** I'm only concerned regarding health issues, I'm not concerned about the plates breaking at all, because if they break it's something I can see and deal with, while if the plates are releasing toxins into my food and damaging my health, that's something I can't detect. **I'd appreciate responses from people who have professional knowledge of these issues, not laymen like me who use common sense.**

Comment: No plate I know of can withstand 250C/480F. That's way over the limit for most utensils designed to be used at a table rather than in an oven.

Comment: Yes, I mean they will crack and break, and some materials _will_ release toxins at those temperatures. I don't know about the material you're asking about specifically, but I do know that if they _can_ release toxins those sorts of temps will do it. Why you choose to break plates instead of washing a pan is mystifying to me. A pan that has seared fish with just a bit of oil would need little more than wiping out.

Comment: I can't find any real research, just *a lot* of stories of Corelle (No longer produced by corningware) shattering, even when just sitting in a cupboard. Here's a list of their do's and dont's, and warn that exceeding them can cause shattering at any time: http://www.corelle.com/use-care-vitrelle.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in https://cooking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a health concern, and is basically opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a small shallow rectangular pyrex dish, bake and eat out of that, it can handle your temperature and if you want one with a lid you could setup your breakfast fish the night before in the fridge.  You absolutely must preheat the oven.

I think that I  saw that you can even go from freezer to preheated oven, but best to ask the makers at pyrex.com they make corelle and corningware too

Comment: They do still explode going from freezer to oven. However, room temperature to oven is fine.

Comment: Welcome to Health SE! Here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) Thanks :)